# Unknown type name with Assimp library

Tags: c, compiler-errors, include, assimp

I'm using the [assimp](https://github.com/assimp/assimp) library within my C project. I installed the library with `sudo apt install libassimp5` and included the following headers:

```c
#include <assimp/cimport.h>
#include <assimp/postprocess.h> 
#include <assimp/scene.h>
```

Everything seems fine at first, but type names like `aiMesh` and `aiScene` are unknown. I'm compiling with the flag `-lassimp` as well. Any idea on why these type names are unknown? Here's what my error looks like:

```
unknown type name ‘aiMesh’
static struct Mesh processMesh(aiMesh *mesh, const aiScene *scene) {
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to inlcude the **mesh.h** nHeader as well:

```
#include <assimp/mesh.h>
```

Hope that helps!